# Filtering out values from a list of object in a List

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, collections

I have an IEnumerable collection of UnitGroup: `IEnumerable<UnitGroup>`,

```
class UnitGroup
    {      
        string key { get; set; }              
        List<UnitType> NameList { get; set; }
    }
class UnitType
    {               
        String UnitName{ get; set; }
        Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to filter`IEnumerable<UnitGroup>` based on UnitType's UnitName.

For example I want to get only the records of UnitName that contains a string and remove remaining.

something like this:

```
IEnumerable<UnitGroup> Groups;
IEnumerable<UnitGroup> filteredResult = Groups.NameList(o => o.UnitName.contains("test"));
```

And get `IEnumerable<UnitGroup>` with only filtered UnitNames under UnitType under UnitGroup.

What is the best way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide some sample data, to make it more clear?

Although, I think it may fit into your goal:

```
IEnumerable<UnitGroup> Groups;
var filteredResult = Groups.Select(g => new UnitGroup {
                                            key = g.key,
                                            NameList = g.NameList
                                                        .Where(n => n.UnitName == "test")
                                                        .ToList()
                                        })
                           .Where(g => g.NameList.Count > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that should do what @MarcinJuraszek answers does.  (I am guessing the intent of the question as well.)

```
IEnumerable<UnitGroup> Groups;
var filteredResult = Groups.Where (g => g.NameList.Count() > g.NameList.RemoveAll(nl => nl.UnitName != "Name1"));
```

If the number of removed items was less than the original count, then we have items that are of interest, so select the parent.

Note: This will modify the original collection, so if you need to filter it more than once then this is not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var filteredList = from g in Groups 
                     where g.NameList.Exists(i=>i.UnitName=="test")
                     select g;
```

Comment: `FindAll()` returns a list not a bool.  `Any()` will do what I think you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Brent: OP asks for an IEnumerable<UnitGroup> as returned by FindAll(): "And get IEnumerable<UnitGroup> with only filtered UnitNames under UnitType under UnitGroup".

Comment: Yes, but a where clause expects the results to be a bool, not a list.

Comment: @Brent: TY; see update. FindAll replaced with Exists, which I believe is the correct criteria.

Comment: Yeah, in this case `Exists()` will work because NameList is a List<T>, but for more general IEnumerable<T> checks the `Any()` Extension method is the choice.

Comment: @Brent: Now I need to go refresh my memory on the precise difference; thanks a lot. ;-)

Comment: Brent is right. where clause is expecting a bool, but anyhow in my solution I can't use Exists or RemoveAll, As my query is on silverlight side, they dropped the RemoveAll and someother functions on silverlight side. All I can do is write an explicit function in a foreach loop. But Marcin solution helped me though.